# Inter-App Communication

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application that accepts input from the user.  The information is used to create a query string which is forwarded to a second application using a custom URL scheme.  The second  application is opened as expected, but the application:openURL method in the AppDelegate of the 2nd application is never visited.  Attached is the code from this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    ProcessorViewController *viewController = (ProcessorViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProcessorController"];

    return [viewController handleURL:url];
}
```

Any assistance determining why this method in the app delegate is never visited would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you add URL types for your custom scheme in project targets?

Comment: fwiw you can test the "opening from url" piece from mobile safari (device or simulator). This could help narrow down the cause.